# Is there a simple way to troublshoot why a program crashes?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn how to code. Instead of having to rewrite programs completely is there a way to find what line of the code has a problem? Or is it normal to have to rewrite everything?

Comment: Might need a bit more information to be able to answer your question. What language are you coding in? Are you getting compilation/execution errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to answer, but I'll do my best

> is there a way to find what line of the code has a problem?

You are using python (judging you question's tag), so run your software from a terminal and every time it crashes you'll bet a stacktrace indicating the line were it failed.

> Or is it normal to have to rewrite everything?

There are some bugs that only require, literally, a one line change, while others may require huge changes to the program to fix them, specially when the problem is related to the logic of the program.

So as you can see there is no simple answer to your question, I recommend you narrow the scope of your doubts and then ask again, also I suggest you to use more 'development oriented' places like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/